# Getting [Error: Credential is missing] using @aws-sdk/client-verifiedpermissions with AWS Cognito for getting Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am using the `IsAuthorizedWithTokenCommand` Command from @aws-sdk/client-verifiedpermissions to get authorization using the identity token generated by cognito, but i am getting the error: `IsAuthorizedWithToken error:  Error: Credential is missing`. What can i do? I already read the documentation, but i'm still lost. This is my code:

```
export function getUserPermission(user: AmplifyUser): boolean | null {
  if (!user) return null;

  const verifiedPermissionsClient = new VerifiedPermissionsClient({
    region: import.meta.env.VITE_POLICYSTOREREGION
  });

  const idToken = user.getSignInUserSession()?.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

  const input: IsAuthorizedWithTokenCommandInput = {
    identityToken: idToken,
    policyStoreId: import.meta.env.VITE_POLICYSTOREID,
  };
  const command = new IsAuthorizedWithTokenCommand(input);

  verifiedPermissionsClient.send(command)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("IsAuthorizedWithToken response: ", response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("IsAuthorizedWithToken error: ", error);
    });

  return null;
}
```

I already tried to pass the acessToken as parameter of `IsAuthorizedWithTokenCommandInput`, but doesn't work either.